# How to display a dropdown based on contents of the current array index in a table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a object array that I want to use in a table.  I need a drop down select if the validvalues has a value.  How to you do this so that each row of the table has different options from the array?  If the validvalues is empty, it should be a div/input in the table row but it validvalues is not empty, it should be a dropdown with the validvalues as the options of the select.

As written, updateOptions() doesn't get called and an empty select shows on every row (insert sad emoji).

TS file

```
tags = [
    {tagName: 'AppID', value: 'T400', validvalues: 'T100/T200/T300/T400/T500'},
    {tagName: 'Series', value: 'SUPR', validvalues: ''},
    {tagName: 'Collection', value: 'AUTO', validvalues: 'EFIT/AUTO/FLEET'},
    {tagName: 'Function', value: 'Accounting', validvalues: 'Sales/Marketing/Accounting/Shop'},
    {tagName: 'Contact', value: 'Jim Jones', validvalues: ''}]

validValuesArray: any = [];


updateOptions(parsingString: string) {
  let tagValidValuesArray = parsingString.split('/');
}
```

HTML file

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Tag Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let tag of tags; let i=index">
    <td>
      <div>{{tag.tagname}}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div *ngIf="!tag.validvalues">
        <input type="text" name="value" [(ngModel)]="tag.value">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="tag.validvalues">
        <select [(ngModel)]="tag.value" (ngChange)="updateOptions(tag.validvalues)">
          <option *ngFor="let value of validValuesArray">{{value}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sure you meant `tag.tagvalues`? That property doesn't exist in your array.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo as it should be tag.validvalues but making that correction still does not provide me the needed results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is/was to load the validValuesArray after tagDtail array is loaded and then use the validValuesArray for the dropdown options.  Like this...

```
for (var m = 0; m < this.tagDtails[0].tags.length; m++){
    let currentTag = this.tagDtails[0].tags[m];

    let parsingString = currentTag.validValues;
    this.validValuesArray.push(parsingString.split('/'));
  }
```

This will create an array or arrays that looks like this:

```
validValuesArray = [
        ["T100","T200","T300","T400","T500"],
        [],
        ["EFIT","AUTO","FLEET"],
        ["Sales","Marketing","Accounting","Shop"],
        []]
```

then, in the html, loop through the validValuesArray

```
<tr *ngFor="let tag of tagDtails.tags; let i = index">
  <td>
    <div>{{ tag.tagName }}</div>
  </td>
  <td class="td-fix">
    <div  *ngIf="this.validValuesArray[i]==''">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tagValue" [(ngModel)]="tag.tagValue">
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="this.validValuesArray[i]!=''">
      <select [(ngModel)]="tag.value">
        <option *ngFor="let value of validValuesArray[i]">{{value}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want your first table row to have a dropdown with the options:

- T100
- T200
- ...

Then your would have to have away to convert your string of `validValues` into an interable type. For example by calling `validValues.split('/')` this would convert your `string` into a `string[]` which you could then loop over.

Since you typically don't want to call methods in your template for performance reasons I would recommend to transform the `validValues` into an Array when you load them, or even before that in your database if possible unless there is a specific reason, why you would hold "a list of Options" as anything but a "listlike" data structure.

Comment: You understand correctly.  IF the validvalues has data, I need it to be the dropdown options on that particular row otherwise that row show have an input instead.  In the TS file, I do have updateOptions function for splitting up the string into an array of options.  It would be possible to split up the string into another array before rendering the html but then how would I reference those options in each row?  From a coding perspective, what would that look like?

Comment: once your validValuesArray is an array you wouldn't need to change anything about your template as fas as I can see. you already have "value" as the variable which iterates through your array and holds the individual strings